# PostgreSQL with JS Drizzle passing array as string getting extra ""

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, drizzle

I'm using Drizzle and I'm passing array variable into Raw SQL

```
const variable = 'value 1,value 4'

SELECT * FROM value_table
WHERE ARRAY [${variable}] && array_values
```

But looking at output I'm getting added extra `""` `params: ["'value 1','value 2'"]`

I have also tried, but same issue

```
WHERE ARRAY (${arr.map((val) => `'${val}'`)}) && array_values
```

How can i pass a variable from JS to SQL array so end result what SQL query will be is

```
SELECT * FROM value_table
WHERE ARRAY ['value 1','value 4'] && array_values

params: ['value 1','value 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, needed to use sql.raw() from Drizzle